# $ 2|f^{'}(0)| = \sup_{z, w \in D} |f(z)-f(w)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, derivatives

Let $D = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{C} $ a disc, $f$ holomorphic on $D$. I want to demonstrate that if $$ 2|f^{'}(0)| = \sup_{z, w \in D} |f(z)-f(w)|$$ 
then $f$ is linear.

I know this is a well-known result. Where can I find the proof ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "On the greatest oscillation of an analytic function in a circle":
http://manetheren.bigw.org/~ray/diampblm.pdf

Comment: It doesn't seem like the link works anymore

Comment: @Math_Day, also answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157587/2f0-sup-z-w-in-d-fz-fw-if-and-only-if-f-is-linear